# Which is better schema for given discussion forum, MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql, scalability

Lets have two variants of nosql collection for storing discussion comments.
Assume discussion, where is only one thread/root comment with 100 replies.

A./

collection: **discussion_thread** (id, discussion_id, comments: Comment[])

- comments is recursive tree structure (Comment = {content: string, comments: [...recursion...]})
  -For given discussion example, there is only one document in discussion_thread, that holds all comments.

B./

collection: **comment** (id, discussion_id, root_comment_id, parent_comment_id, content) *-- I know there could be slug*

- For given discussion example, there will be 101 documents in comment collection

---

Lets assume:

- the database has 500GB and is growing, collections are sharded by discussion_id with master/slave replication
- we have 1000 request /minute, 90% reads
- on each write (e.g. upvote of comment) we need to rebuild the cache for whole thread, for fast read/serving

---

To be reasonably brief, in this question I would like to focus only on cache rebuilding. So we need to read all the comments for given thread / root_comment.

In A./ we need one lookup to get 1 document with all comments.
But this structure is quite problematic to write into(at least because potentially all concurent writes to single thread ends up on one document).

In B./ to get all of the 101 comments of the example thread, mongo needs to find and return 101 documents.
Because there is index on discussion_id and root_comment_id and sharding on discussion_id, do you think, that the B variant will be significantly slower then the A?

Do You think there is some other major disadvantage in one of the variants?
Thanks.